# Using Jquery with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My `jQuery` is not working, i don't know what am i doing wrong.

The button is supposed to hide the paragraph and bring it back when i press it.
Have put the html and `toggle.js` code.
I am referencing the `jquery` library from a folder called `js`.

**HTML**

```
<DOCTYPE = html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <script src=  "js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/toggle.js"></script>

    <title>Jquery Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "button" value = "Hide" id = "toggle_message"/>
    <p id = "message">You can see this paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**TOGGLE.JS**

```
$('#toggle_message').click(function() {

  var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
  $('#message').toggle('fast');

  if (value == 'Hide') {
    $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Show');
  } else if (value == 'Show') {
    $('#toggle_message').attr('value','Hide');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try wrapping your code with `$(function() {});`
It likely can't access the DOM yet.
e.g

```
$(function() {

    $('#toggle_message').click(function() {

      var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
      $('#message').toggle('fast');

      if (value == 'Hide') {
        $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Show');
      } else if (value == 'Show') {
        $('#toggle_message').attr('value','Hide');
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = "button" value = "Hide" id="toggle_message"/>
        <p id = "message">You can see this paragraph</p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#toggle_message').click(function() {        
                var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
                $('#message').toggle('fast');

                if (value == 'Hide') {
                    $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Show');
                } else if (value == 'Show') {
                    $('#toggle_message').attr('value','Hide');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I was missing "$(document).ready( function () " on top of the script.Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your `click` handler attaches to the DOM even before your elements are present in the DOM.

Enclose the code in your `toggle.js` like this:

```
$(function(){
  // your code here

});
```

Alternatively, you can place your script tag after the elements actually attach to the DOM, like:

```
<DOCTYPE = html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <script src=  "js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>


    <title>Jquery Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "button" value = "Hide" id = "toggle_message"/>
    <p id = "message">You can see this paragraph</p>

    <script src = "js/toggle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<body>
    <input type = "button" value = "Hide" id = "toggle_message"/>
    <p id = "message">You can see this paragraph</p>
</body>


<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#toggle_message').click(function() {

            var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
            $('#message').toggle('fast');

            if (value == 'Hide') {
              $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Show');
            } else if (value == 'Show') {
              $('#toggle_message').attr('value','Hide');
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine as you can see [here](https://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/gPNjvX?editors=1010).

The reason why it dosen't in your case is beacuse the DOM is loaded after the javascript code runs so you need to wrap your code in document ready

`$( document ).ready()`

or a self invoking anonymous function or better yet include the script just before the closing body tag so it runs after the DOM is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine, just put your `toggle.js` code in a function like
`$( document ).ready() {   }`

Your `toggle.js` should be-

```
$( document ).ready() {
 $('#toggle_message').click(function() {

  var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
  $('#message').toggle('fast');

  if (value == 'Hide') {
    $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Show');
  } else if (value == 'Show') {
    $('#toggle_message').attr('value','Hide');
  }
 });
}
```

and always include Javascript files at the bottom of the page i,e before `</body>` tag.